# forever with nodemon not working in node js

Tags: node.js, forever, nodemon

hello i am trying to run node server with forever like below

```
forever start -c nodemon app.js
```

when i run this command on terminal it shows below line and when i hit api  path it gives server not running

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js
```

and node does not work can anyone guide where i am missing

Thanks

Comment: path and environment correct?

Comment: yes as if it was wrong it should have given error like error:   script /path/to/app/nodemon does not exist.

Comment: start               Start SCRIPT as a daemon

can you explain what do you need exactly?
https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Comment: actually, i want to run forever with nodemon so that my node app can run continuously while if there is some error too

Comment: forever only daemonizing tool. You have to find another decision.